# FlutterFragment is not retaining state

Tags: flutter

I am trying to embed a Flutter app inside my existing Android app using this steps:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps

I am embedding the `FlutterFragment` inside my Activity in `onCreate` method, but when I rotate the screen, the fragment **does not** retain it's state.

This is MainActivity code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().also {
            it.replace(android.R.id.content, Flutter.createFragment(null), "flutter")
        }.commit()
    } else {
        val flutterFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("flutter")
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().also {
            it.attach(flutterFragment!!)
        }.commit()
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably not declaring your Activity properly. The `configChanges` are very important for Flutter to work with Android's lifecycle.

You have to declare it on the `AndroidManifest` like this:

```
<activity
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```

Comment: Daniel, are you using this technique in production? I'm concerned b/c it comes from a page that says "do not use in production, we will break you"

Comment: Yes, production.